# Submitting a form with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have an instance in which I use the event of clicking the submit button to populate a field in my form with value. But, now, I can't get the form to submit at the same time. What can I do?

http://jsfiddle.net/cmfZX/14/

Comment: "return false;" stops the default browser behaviour

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just don't return `false` from your form's submit handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/cmfZX/15/

Not a lot more to say than that...

Answer (score 2):

Your event handler returns `false`. Event handlers should return *anything* other than `false` or nothing in order for the default behavior to occur.

[This article](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) might be a good read for you.

Comment: Actually *anything* other than `false` will suffice - even `null` and `0` don't stop it submitting. Certainly in Chrome. Good link though, +1 for that.

Comment: @DaveRandom, Good clarification.

Answer (score 1):

That last `return false` is preventing the form from submitting. Once you pull that out, it should run just fine. You may also want to consider updating the form field with the JSON inside the first onclick event, that way you don't have to do anything special on submit.

Comment: you must of read this posted 3 times before you added yours. great answer but seems a little pointless.

Comment: Actually, when I opened the page there were no answers here. I made the mistake of getting distracted and answering five minutes later and only saw the other answers after submitting mine. Oh well